# Drivers to get a BU-353 S$ gps dongle working on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers

I am new to ubuntu and Linux and want to use my gps i was using on Windows to work in OpenCPN using Ubuntu

Is there a site where i can load a set of drivers and get the gps to work

I have been to the OEM site and they only have drivers for Redhat

Can you help me or guide me step by step on what to do in command to get it operating

Comment: I suspect that the driver, *pl2303* is a;ready built in to Ubuntu. I suggest that you run the terminal command: `tail -f /var/log/syslog`and insert the device. Watch the terminal to see what is reported. Get out of tail with Ctrl+c. Also check if the driver loaded: `lsmod | grep pl23` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome

Comment: Here's how I tested my pl2303 GPS dongle in UBuntu long ago: http://cheesehead-techblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/gps-dongle-gpsd-and-ubuntu-1110.html

Answer (score 2):

You  don't need a *driver*. You need a GPS daemon to listen for signal from the dongle.

- Try: `sudo apt install gpsd`
- Then run the `gpsmon` application to test that you are receiving location data.